# What does semicolon-termination inside a Makefile's define directive do?

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I'm wondering what the semicolons in the following makefile snippet do:

```
define Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.h, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/xxsim);
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.cpp, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR));
endef
Hooks/Prepare/Post+=Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles
```

In case it matters, the makefile is for a custom component (xxsim) in the OpenWRT buildsystem.

I would expect that the semicolons are unnecessary, per, e.g., this example ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html)):

```
define two-lines =
    echo foo
    echo $(bar)
endef
```

However, if we build without those semicolons, the second call to `cp` fails (the first call to `cp` is implicitly successful):

```
 [CP]        files/Adapter20Sim.h
 [CP]        files/Adapter20Sim.cpp
 cp: target ' [MKDIR]    xxsim docinfo in staging dir' is not a directory
```

Clearly, cp receives incorrect input parameters. So, what does adding the semicolons actually do, why does the component build correctly with semicolons present?

**Update:** added buildsystem context below, resulting from Etan's help in the comments:

The `Hooks/Prepare/Post` is used in a foreach statement, where each of its values is used in a call function:

```
$(foreach hook,$(Hooks/Prepare/Post),$(call $(hook))$(sep))
```

The context of the `foreach`:

```
 $(STAMP_PREPARED) : export PATH=$$(TARGET_PATH_PKG)
 $(STAMP_PREPARED):| $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) $(STAGING_DIR)/include $(STAGING_DIR)/lib$(LIB_SUFFIX)
    $(foreach hook,$(Hooks/Prepare/Pre),$(call $(hook))$(sep))
    $(Build/Prepare)
    $(foreach hook,$(Hooks/Prepare/Post),$(call $(hook))$(sep))
    $(call touch,$$@,Prepared $(PKG_NAME))
```

Comment: How is `Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles` used in that makefile? The `Hooks/Prepare/Post` assignment line is only part of the usage. It has to be expanded/referenced somewhere.

Comment: As far as I know, the buildsystem takes care of expanding all values in the variable `Hooks/Prepare/Post`. The buildsystem is also responsible for "calling" the makefile, as each component (of which xxsim is one) has its own makefile.

Could it matter how it is used?

Comment: Yes, it will. Use it in a make recipe directly and it expands to two lines. Use it in some other context (shell, etc.) and it might expand to a single line (which would then require semi-colons to terminate commands).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I looked it up, Hooks/Prepare/Post is used in a `foreach` statement, where each of its values is used in a `call` function: `$(foreach hook,$(Hooks/Prepare/Post),$(call $(hook))$(sep))`. As far as I've been able to find, `$(hook)` shouldn't expand to a single line, right?

Comment: Of course it does; it expands to each token in the input list in turn.

Comment: @tripleee `hook` contains the name of the define being expanded. The question is why is `$(call $(hook))` expanding the define as a single line.

Comment: What context is that `foreach` in? That looks to be expanding to multiple lines (but without a trailing newline) and then the next command is on the same line and getting confused. (The first and second `cp` calls seem to be separated even without the semicolons.)

Comment: @Etan I added context info to the question. The next command is `touch`, not `cp`, so that's not the command that gives the error.

Comment: The output indicates that a `mkdir` command is getting attached to the `cp` command. Are you sure that's not the next hook? What is `$(sep)`?

Comment: If you remove the semicolons and add a blank line after that second `cp` call in the define does the error go away? (I'm not sure if make collapses all trailing newlines in a define but it removes at least one.)

Comment: @Etan You were right, the `mkdir` was part of the next hook and a newline fixed it. Thanks for the help! Apparently, OpenWRT hooks are intended to be single line. We changed all define directives that are used in hooks to conform to this. Could you create an answer from your comments, so that I can mark that as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is how a multi-line define is expanded in a recipe context (and specifically what the contents of the define are).

In a recipe context a multi-line define is expanded as multiple lines so the example from the make manual works correctly.

You would assume, as such, that the scenario under discussion here would work as well which it clearly doesn't. Two things combine to cause this problem.

The first of which is what the value of the define is exactly.

You might assume that given this snippet:

```
PKG_BUILD_DIR := build
cp = @echo '[CP] $1'; cp '$1' '$2'

define Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.h, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/xxsim)
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.cpp, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR))
endef
```

that the value of `Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles` would be:

```
@echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.h'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.h' 'build/xxsim'
@echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.cpp'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.cpp' 'build'
```

and it is... except.

You *might* assume that that was two lines with two newlines so really this:

```
@echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.h'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.h' 'build/xxsim'\n
@echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.cpp'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.cpp' 'build'\n
```

but it isn't. What it actually is is this:

```
@echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.h'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.h' 'build/xxsim'\n
@echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.cpp'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.cpp' 'build'
```

with **no** final newline.

Now normally (and in the example in the makefile) that doesn't matter because the define is used something like this:

```
tgt:
        $(Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles)
```

and the final character of the define is followed immediately by a newline (on the recipe line itself).

But that isn't what is happening in this case. In this case the define is being expanded in a `$(foreach)` loop and the manual says this about `foreach`:

> The multiple expansions of *text* are concatenated, with spaces between them, to make the result of *foreach*.

So when the loop expands two such defines back-to-back:

```
mkdir = @echo '[MKDIR] $1'; mkdir '$1'

define Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.h, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/xxsim)
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.cpp, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR))
endef
HOOKS += Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles
define Package/xxsim/MkdirStaging
    $(call mkdir, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/xxsim/staging)
endef
HOOKS += Package/xxsim/MkdirStaging

tgt:
        $(foreach hook,$(HOOKS),$(call $(hook)))
```

what you get as the expanded output is this:

```
tgt:
    @echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.h'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.h' 'build/xxsim'
    @echo '[CP] files/Adapter20Sim.cpp'; cp 'files/Adapter20Sim.cpp' 'build' @echo '[MKDIR] build/xxsim/staging'; mkdir build/xxsim/staging
```

which causes the error you are seeing and which including the trailing semi-colons fixes.

Including an additional blank line in the define might also solve the problem (if make only chomps a single newline off the end of the literal define value).

Like this:

```
define Package/xxsim/CopyLocalFiles
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.h, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/xxsim)
    $(call cp, files/Adapter20Sim.cpp, $(PKG_BUILD_DIR))

endef
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such an extensive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon has no special functionality in a define function. `$(call  MyDefine)` does nothing more than expanding the define function, i.e. the `call` function is replaced by the contents of the `define` function.

(The `call` function does actually some other things, like parameter expansion, but that does not seem to have influence on this subject.)

In you situation the the semicolons are required as the copy commands are expanded in such a way that both are executed at once. A shell (like bash) required semicolons between two commands.

Makefile syntax uses tabs to define commands that belong to a target. Your error

> cp: target ' [MKDIR]    xxsim docinfo in staging dir' is not a directory`

suggests that one of your commands (or something..??) is handled as a target instead of a command. If the contents of the `define` function has spaces as indentation, you might want to replace them by tabs, so the complete content is inserted as commands, instead of target(s).

Another solution is to add backslashes after each line, making the contents 'single-line'. In this situation, the semicolons are required as the single-line is executed by the shell, so all commands need to be separated by them.

Comment: While almost all of this is true it doesn't exactly cover the problem at hand. Specifically the bit about leading spaces vs. tabs is simply incorrect. A multi-line define expands correctly in recipe context regardless of leading whitespace in the define as long as the define expansion itself is tabbed. Try it and see.

Comment: Oh interesting! Is this new behavior of make? As I could have sworn that I have had such problems in the past where I mixed tab and space indentation in defines...

Comment: It is the behavior in 3.81 (and I assume all newer versions) I haven't tried any older versions so I don't know. If you are *creating* a target in a define (with `eval` or similar) then you might need the right spacing but I'm not sure.